# Problem with dispatch() and if-else statement after adding another method

Tags: firebase, react-native, if-statement, promise, dispatch

I have this action to fetch the details of a specific location url stored in Firebase.

The original code (Version 1) worked no problem, whereby I dispatch authGetToken(), the code recognises the token (string) stored in redux, then uses it to to fetch the stored data.

### Version 1

```
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(authGetToken())
            .then(token => {
                return fetch("https://myProject/location.json?auth=" + token);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                alert("No valid token found!");
            })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.ok) {
                    return res.json();
                } else {
                    throw(new Error());
                }
            })
        };
```

But now that I modified the url requirements to include the user UID as part of the url, it does not work. I know there must be a flaw in my logic but I can't see it.

What I was hoping to write is that once I dispatch authGetToken(), the token dispatches authGetUserUID then uses both strings (userUID and token) to fetch the data.

### Version 2

```
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(authGetToken())
            .then(token => {
                dispatch(authGetuserUID())
                return fetch("https://myProject/location/"+ userUID + ".json?auth=" + token);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                alert("No valid token found!");
            })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.ok) {
                    return res.json();
                } else {
                    throw(new Error());
                }
            })
        };
```

Would appreciate you guys pointing out the obvious to me >< as I my noob eyes can't see it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have something to do with `userUID`, it doesn't seem to be initialised anywhere. Maybe try something like this:

```
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(authGetToken()).then(token => {
                dispatch(authGetuserUID()).then(userUID=>{
                   return fetch("https://myProject/location/"+ userUID + ".json?auth=" + token);
                })

            })
            .catch(() => {
                alert("No valid token found!");
            })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.ok) {
                    return res.json();
                } else {
                    throw(new Error());
                }
            })
        };
```

Comment: No dice :( I still can't get a res... I think the problem might lie in my backend of storing userUID. But thanks for your help!